# Up to a change of coordinates, what does $\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x})/\|\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x})\|$ looks like?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization

---

**First part: motivations**

---

*If you don't bother with optimization, you can skip this part*.

---

While I was studying KKT points of quadratic penalty method applied to the optimization problems \begin{align} \min_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} &\  f(x) \\ \text{st} &\  h(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{0} \\
&\  g(\boldsymbol{x}) \leq \boldsymbol{0} 
\end{align} I ended up with a question. Let us start with an increasing and unbounded sequence $\{ \rho_k \}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and the quadratic penalty function $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{n}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by $\Phi(\boldsymbol{x}) = \left(\|\max\{\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{x}),0\}\|^2_{2} + \| \boldsymbol{h}(\boldsymbol{x})\|^2_{2}\right)$, for all $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Let us suppose that an external penalty method generates a converging sequence of stationary points, say $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ for the extermal penalty method subproblem \begin{align} \min_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} &\  f(x)+ \rho_k \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}),
\end{align} i.e., a sequence so that $$\nabla f(\boldsymbol{x}^{k}) + \rho_k \nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{k}) = 0.$$ Now observe that $$\dfrac{1}{\|\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x}^k) \|_{2}}\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x}^k) = - \dfrac{1}{\|\nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{k})\|_{2}} \nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{k}).$$ This means that, the only possible way of having
a converging sequence stationary point $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is that $$\left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{\|\nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{k})\|_{2}} \nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{k})\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ converges.}$$ Now, in order to make the things more interesting, let $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to a feasible point, say $\boldsymbol{x}^{*}$, i.e., $\Phi(\boldsymbol{x}^{*}) = \boldsymbol{0}$. This also implies that $\nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x}^{*}) = \boldsymbol{0},$ i.e., a "singular point".

---

**Second part: question**

---

Now comes the question:

> Considering the zero set of $\nabla \Phi$, i.e., $\mathcal{Z} := \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \nabla \Phi(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{0}\}$. How does the function $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \mathcal{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $g(x) = \nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x})/\|\nabla \Phi (\boldsymbol{x})\|$ behaves by a change of coordinate, or even a proper surjective map? Is this a projection onto $\mathcal{Z}$ by changing coordinates? Specifically, by finding a differentiable proper and surjective map $\theta : \mathbb{R}^{m} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$, how is the basic form of $g \circ \theta $? Does Whitney stratification helps to find this basic form? What does it say?

Take easy on me, I'm an applied mathematician. =) On Whitney stratification thing, If an easy, maybe extremely easy, reference can be found, it would be enlightening!

Comment: Why would you guess that $g$ is projection on to $Z$? That's obviously not the case in general - $g$ lands on the unit sphere. Your $g$ is just the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map).

Comment: What is the general form of a Gauss map? Does It look like a projection? Note that I am asking this after the change of coordinates is done. What does It look like.? I thought Whitney stratification theorem would help me with It. My question is quite deep. It's about characterization of Guass maps in terms of simple functions.

Comment: Given a manifold, the Gauss map takes each point to the point on the sphere that is its unit normal. I don't see why Whitney stratification would be helpful here. Your question appears to be in a weird superposition of you not really understanding what's going on but also clearly having left some of your knowledge out - if there's context you've left out (like why you think Whitney stratification should help), I think you should add it to your post. Until you make things clearer with an edit, I don't think I have much to say.

Comment: Due to the maximum in its definition, $\Phi$ is probably not differentiable. So I'm a bit confused- why does this question assume $\nabla\Phi$ exists?

For every $x$, if we asume $\nabla\Phi(x)$ exists and is nonzero, $g(x)$ is the projection of $\nabla\Phi(x)$ onto the unit sphere. I'd imagine that normalizing will not provide a projection onto the set of zeros in general.

Comment: The quadratic penaty method function is differentiable. The derivative is Lipschitz whenever the constraint have Lipschitz derivative  as well.

Comment: The intuition is that minimizing the $\Phi$ will probably reaching a value close to the projection. Hence, changing It a bit, It should look a projection.